# Switch template type

Tags: c++, templates, types, dictionary

I want to make some storage for my game. Now the code looks like:

```
class WorldSettings
{
    private:
        std::map<std::string, int> mIntegerStorage;
        std::map<std::string, float> mFloatStorage;
        std::map<std::string, std::string> mStringStorage;

    public:
        template <typename T>
        T Get(const std::string &key) const
        {
            // [?]
        }
};
```

So, I have a few associative containers which stores the exact type of data. Now I want to add into settings some value: `settings.Push<int>("WorldSize", 1000);` and get it: `settings.Get<int>("WorldSize");`. But how to switch need map due to passed type into template?

Or, maybe, you know a better way, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your compiler supports this<sup>1</sup>, you can use template function specialisations:

```
class WorldSettings
{
    private:
        std::map<std::string, int> mIntegerStorage;
        std::map<std::string, float> mFloatStorage;
        std::map<std::string, std::string> mStringStorage;

    public:
        template <typename T>
        T Get(const std::string &key); // purposely left undefined
};

...

template<>
int WorldSettings::Get<int>(const std::string& key) {
    return mIntegerStorage[key];
}

template<>
float WorldSettings::Get<float>(const std::string& key) {
    return mFloatStorage[key];
}

// etc
```

Notice that the methods are not `const` because `map<>::operator[]` is not `const`.

Also, if someone tries to use the template with a type other than one you have provided a specialisation for, they will get linker errors, so your code won't misbehave or anything. Which is optimal.

---

<sup>1</sup> If not, see [@gwiazdorrr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220045/switch-template-type/8220181#8220181)

Comment: @Ockonal yes it is. Template specialisations are one of the most useful features introduced by C++11.

Comment: While template function specializations are neat, they are not C++11 specific. They're not appropriate in all cases, due to how they interact with normal function overloading. This is one of the cases where they are appropriate. See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm

Comment: @DaveS when were template function specialisations introduced if not in C++11? I don't think C++03 had them did it?

Comment: @Seth Section 14.7.3 `An explicit specialization of any of the following: function template ...`, which then has an example `template<class T> void sort(Array<T>& v) { /* ... */ } template<> void sort<char*>(Array<char*>&) ;`

Comment: @DaveS wow, I never knew that, that's cool. Thanks. Why is compiler support bad for this? (Or am I just imagining that it's bad?)

Comment: Very slick. You just saved me about an hour.

Answer (score 8):

<strike>First of all, since prior to C++11 you can't specialise functions, your member functions must differ in signature - return type does not count. From my experience on some compilers you can do without it, but as usual - you should keep your code as close to standard as possible.</strike>

That said you can add a dummy paramater that won't affect performance and the way you call function:

```
public:
    template <typename T>
    T Get(const std::string &key) const
    {
        return GetInner(key, (T*)0);
    }

private:
    int GetInner(const std::string& key, int*) const
    {
        // return something from mIntegerStorage
    }

    float GetInner(const std::string& key, float*) const
    {
        // return something from mFloatStorage
    }
```

And so on. You get the idea.

Comment: Yep, very interesting idea. Will remember this.

Comment: This is a really good way of doing it without template specialisations. I would recommend using references than pointers for numerous reasons though, but still, +1

Comment: I use pointers because you can always assign 0 to them. How exactly you would use references?

Comment: You do not need to add the dummy pointer to the interface, it can just forward to ‘GetInner(key,(T*)0)‘, that is the extra pointer is a detail that should not modify the public interface.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the purpose of the second argument.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Hmmm it was quite some time ago since I had applied this pattern, I'll fix the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Rather than providing the different `GetInner` functions it would be better if you provided `map<string,X> const & GetStorage( X* ) const` overloads that return a reference to the appropriate container, that way you can remove redundant code (lookup in the container, error conditions... need not be duplicated in each `GetInner` function, and can rather be handled in the `Get` template)

Answer (score 2):

Seth's answer is ideal, but if you don't have access to a C++11 compiler, then you can use template class specialization and do this instead. It's much more verbose, but keeps the same functionality.

```
class WorldSettings
{
    template<class T>
    struct Selector;
    template<class T>
    friend struct Selector;

private:
    std::map<std::string, int> mIntegerStorage;
    std::map<std::string, float> mFloatStorage;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mStringStorage;

public:
    template <typename T>
    T Get(const std::string &key)
    {
        return Selector<T>::Get(*this)[key];
    }
};

template<>
struct WorldSettings::Selector<int>
{
    static std::map<std::string, int> & Get(WorldSettings &settings)
    {
        return settings.mIntegerStorage;
    }
};

template<>
struct WorldSettings::Selector<float>
{
    static std::map<std::string, float> & Get(WorldSettings &settings)
    {
        return settings.mFloatStorage;
    }
};

// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 I would recommend the use of ‘boost::any‘ in the type of the container, and the. You need a single accessor:

```
std::map<std::string,boost::any> storage;
template <typename T> getValue( std::string const & key ) {
   return boost::any_cast<T>( storage[key] );
}
```

This is a rough sketch, as a member function It would be const, and it should use ‘map::find‘ not to modify the container when searching, it should deal with invalid joeys, and probably remap the boost exceptions into your own application exceptions.

Comment: Doesn't that increase memory consumption and fragmentation, (boost::any allocates an inner object IIRC) and computation costs (inner virtual functions, comparing `type_id`)? I know this may be not a critical part of the game code, but those are the things you should avoid as a part of your policy.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: For settings and configuration, you should use whatever is easier and simpler to maintain. Performance is overrated by many but you need to know where it matters and where it does not. You are right in that this solution uses more memory, involves dynamic allocations and some RTTI. If you need performance, forget about the maps altogether and use a handcrafted class with as many methods as required, but in most cases if the dynamic allocations in the map are not an issue, then the use of `boost::any` shouldn't either.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion. Maps are slow to insert (node allocation), but the lookup is fairly fast. So provided you don't insert or remove nodes too often (e.g. you do it only in initialisation stage) it is a good choice. `boost::any` is slow no matter what and while I agree it has its use, it seems like a bloated solution for given problem.